# How can I import a character vector from R saved as RData to a python list?

Tags: python, r, rpy2

How can I import a character vector from R saved as RData to a python list?

For example, if I have saved this character vector in R:

```
x <- c("Hello", "world!")
save (x, file = 'x.RData')
```

Then loaded in python with `rpy2` as follows:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri,r
import rpy2.robjects as robjects

def main():
    r['load']('x.RData')
    variables = tuple(robjects.globalenv.keys())
    print('variables: {0}'.format(variables))
    x = robjects.globalenv['x']
    print('x: {0}'.format(x))
    print('type(x): {0}'.format(type(x)))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

which prints:

```
variables: ('x',)
x: [1] "Hello"  "world!"
type(x): <class 'rpy2.robjects.vectors.StrVector'>
```

How can I import it to a python list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply cast it with `list()`:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri,r
import rpy2.robjects as robjects

def main():
    r['load']('x.RData')
    variables = tuple(robjects.globalenv.keys())
    print('variables: {0}'.format(variables))
    x = robjects.globalenv['x']
    print('x: {0}'.format(x))
    print('type(x): {0}'.format(type(x)))
    print('list(x): {0}'.format(list(x)))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```